# How can I remove in Python lines within a string that has words and breakline?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I'm writing a scraper and I get a string with a word and a number. You can see the result below.

```
CODE WITHOUT REPLACE("Plugin Goo") Parameter:
    if "Inhalt" in i:
    clean_1 = i[128:138]
    clean_2 = clean_1.replace(">", "")
    clean_2 = clean_2.replace("</", "")
    clean_2 = clean_2.replace('\n', " ")
    print(clean_2)

RESULT WITHOUT REPLACE("Plugin Goo") Parameter:
Plugin Goo
0,330 l
```

My expected result is also shown below:

```
0,330 l
```

I only want the number "0,330 l" which is in the first and only row.

I've tried to use the replace() function which gets as parameter "\n". The code + the result of the code is shown below:

CODE WITH REPLACE("Plugin Goo") Parameter:

```
if "Inhalt" in i:
    clean_1 = i[128:138]
    clean_2 = clean_1.replace(">", "")
    clean_2 = clean_2.replace("</", "")
    clean_2 = clean_2.replace('\n', " ")
    clean_2 = clean_2.replace('Plugin Goo', "").strip()
    print(len(clean_2))
    print(clean_2)
```

RESULT WITH REPLACE("Plugin Goo") Parameter:

```
0
7
Here is the empty row which is still there but with null value
0,330 l
```

As you can see I have removed the word "Plugin Goo" but the line is still existing.

Comment: Why do you not use `clean_2.split("\n")[1]`?

Comment: Why do you do other stuff in the code that isn't mentioned in the text above? Which part of the code does the text refer to?

Comment: When I used clean_2.split("\n")[1] then I get the Exception: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ive added the code for the first result. Also Ive added the prints for the result.

Comment: Why does the "CODE WITHOUT REPLACE" use `replace` 3 times? Where are the 0 and 7 coming from in the last result?

Comment: Ok ok I see I didnt write it very well. Im sorry. I will edit it. But I meant without the replace which has the "Plugin Goo" as parameter. The 0 and 7 are coming from the first print (print(len(clean_2))). I just wanted to show that the String in the first row is empty but still there.

Comment: You're not super clear on your inputs and outputs - and you should clean up the code editing so it's runnable. That said, `clean_2.split("\n")` is what you want. That will give you a list of strings that is your original string split on each newline character. `clean_2.split("\n")[1]` will fail if that list is only length 0 or 1, which is why you typically deal with the output in a loop.